# What is the largest size limit (in Mb) for html video tag on iOS mobile devices

Tags: ios, video, html5-video

I've noticed that my server-hosted video that is larger than 19 MB (I've made some test with video size range from 10 to 30 MB to figured it out) doesn't work on iOS mobile devices.

What is the maximum size limit (in MB) for the video html tag on iOS mobile devices?